# Borrowing Neurons

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

This idea came to me in church.  I am not much for religion however the example would make it an ideal place for such a product.  I notice in church my brain productivity drops by at least half.  So I was thinking if there is there a way to harness all this unused brain power from everyone in church.  Just from these 300 individuals, it would be the most powerful computer on the planet.

If a company could create a way to rent out a percentage of neurons from individuals brains, how would this be implemented and where?

Comment: Renting out a percentage of neurons from individuals brains is already a thing, it's called advertising.

Comment: In the *original * storyline of "The Matrix", human brains were the prize the machines wanted, not as a power plant, but as shared computational capacity, you could consider a similar approach.  Neural interfaces beyond a non-invasive external sensor  are still mostly the stuff of Sci-fi, although most of the concepts are sound.  'Borrowing' computational space on a brain may involve unpleasantries, such as invasive wiring, or in the extreme fictional example, fully "BORG" like takeover.

Comment: You do computation every day for google just by being online and connected to the millions of sites using google analytics.

Comment: Perhaps your productivity halves because your brain is being borrowed.

Comment: This is a wonderful idea, reflecting the very best of speculative fiction, which is to say, that speculation which is used as a form of social allegory.  *(Quite distinct from what might be termed ["schlock"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/schlock), and which comprises the bulk of any given medium or genre;)*

Comment: How about ... Hire somebody like me. I was a tech consultant for over 30 years; working on new devices, machines, equipment, software, and solving problems for Fortune 100 companies on products under development. I rented out about a third of my neurons every 24 hours every day. Your premise is wrong, though, neurons are not interchangeable transistors or reconfigurable. Mine and yours, even if magically separable, won't work with each other; they require intricate physical entanglement; they don't "run code" like a computer. The intertwining ***is*** the code; undoing it destroys the brain.

Answer (score 1):

Market your brain sucking machine as a new adult entertainment medium.  Since you already need an advanced brain-computer interface to handle the partitioning of the donor brain into conscious and unconscious sections, the delivery of tasks to the unconscious portion and the return-routing of any results, leveraging that interface to stimulate the pleasure centers of the donor brain should be a minor enhancement.

While the majority of the donor's mind is busy contributing to the search for a cure to cancer, the conscious minimum would be riding along on a journey of erotic bliss.

If you make it enjoyable enough for the donors, they might even pay you for the privilege of getting to donate.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into too much detail, which I don't think is necessary to explicate this wonderful idea, I'd say use quantum mechanics.

- Make human thought involve quantum phenomenon

(See [the Free Will Theorem](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/do-subatomic-particles-have-free-will).)

Computing is based on decisions, and decisions are an expression of "will".  Since you use a religious context, tying it into this issue of central importance in modern religions would greatly strengthen the work.

- Quantum entanglement is used to remotely access the brains for processing

This stretches the idea into the realm of "magical realism", which I don't think is inappropriate. "[Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Sunshine_of_the_Spotless_Mind)" demonstrates how you can breeze past the technical aspects to develop your allegory.

I'd also highly recommend [reading the stories of George Saunders](http://www.openculture.com/2013/03/10_free_stories_by_george_saunders_author_of_itenth_of_decemberi_the_best_book_youll_read_this_year.html), who is extraordinarily well regarded, and writes about the human condition in a technological society.  His work also feels consistent with the spirit of your wonderful idea.